# Is there an easier way to make 4 rows of 15 sprites?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm pretty sure there is an easier way to do this, but I've either forgotten how to do it or it's more complicated than I think it is. Here's what I have:

```
class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([25, 25])
        self.image.fill(color)
        self.color = color
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

This is the sprite I am going to be using.

```
# Block
margin = 50
for i in range(15):
    block = Block(black)
    block.rect.x = 30 + margin*i
    block.rect.y = 25
    block_list.add(block)

for i in range(15):
    block = Block(black)
    block.rect.x = 30 + margin*i
    block.rect.y = 75
    block_list.add(block)
    
for i in range(15):
    block = Block(black)
    block.rect.x = 30 + margin*i
    block.rect.y = 125
    block_list.add(block)

for i in range(15):
    block = Block(black)
    block.rect.x = 30 + margin*i
    block.rect.y = 175
    block_list.add(block)
```

When I am adding in the `block` sprite (in 4 rows of 15), I used four for loops to draw what I am trying to achieve. Is there a more simple way for me to do this? I'm almost certain that there is, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: You can use for loops inside other for loops

Comment: Oh right, thank you. I completely forgot about that.

Comment: use better names: `for row in range(4): for column in range(15): ... block.rect.x = 30 + margin*column; block.rect.y = 25 + margin*row`

Answer (score 0):

```
margin = 50
for column in range(4):
    for row in range(15):
        alien = Alien(green)
        alien.rect.x = 30 + margin*row
        alien.rect.y = 25 + margin *column
        alien_list.add(alien)
        all_sprites_list.add(alien)
```

For loop within a for loop works.